# prove $x^p\cdot\ln(x)$ is uniform continuous on $(0,1]$ where $0 < p < 1$

Tags: real-analysis

prove $x^p\cdot\ln(x)$ is uniform continuous on $(0,1]$ where $0 < p < 1$.

$\forall \epsilon >0$

I tried to find a $\delta>0$ such that
$|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<$.

WLOG $1>x>y>0$

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|x^p\ln(x)-y^p\ln(y)|
\leqslant|x^p-y^p||\ln(x)|+|y^p||\ln(x)-\ln(y)|$

But it is not bounded by a scaler times $|y-x|$.

Thanks.

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks for editing. This is the first time using LaTeX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{x \to 0} x^{p}\log \, x=0$ (by L'Hopital's Rule)so we can extend the function to a continuous function on $[0,1]$. Any continuous function on $[0,1]$ is uniformly continuous so the given function is also uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^p\ln x=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln x}{x^{-p}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac1{-px^{-p}}=0$$
the function can be extended to
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}x^p\ln x&\text{ if }&0<x\le 1\\0&\text{ if }&x=0\end{cases}$$
which is continuous and its domain is compact.

Then $ g$ has a minimum $m$ and a maximum $M$ and $|g(x)-g(y)|\le M-m$ for $x,y\in[0,1]$.

Comment: This does  not prove uniform continuity.